# Peter planted a tree. Its growth is given by $h(t) = \frac{a}{1+be^{kt}}$ for $t$ years. Find $a$,$b$ and $k$

Tags: calculus

> Peter planted a tree on his backyard. Over the course of some years he
>   measured the height of the tree. first directly, and later on using
>   his knowledge of trigonometry. When he thought he had enough data, he
>   defined as the model for the growth of the tree in meters, after $t$
>   years of being planted,  the following function:
>
> $$h(t) = \frac{a}{1+be^{kt}}$$
>
> Determine $a$,$b$ and $k$, knowing that:
>
> - the tree was 50 cm tall when it was planted
> - the maximum height the tree can have is 5 meters (approximate value)
> - after 2 years, the tree has twice the height it had when it was planted

(Note: " *5 meters (approximate value)*" is an exact quote)

I did:

$50 cm = 0.5m$,

$$0.5 = \frac{a}{1+be^{-k\cdot0}} \Leftrightarrow 0.5 = \frac{a}{1+b}$$

so I conlcude that

$a = \frac{b+1}{2}$ and $b = 2a-1$

Then I used the information on the third item,

$h(2) = 1$

and I tried to isolate $k$

$$1 = \frac{\frac{b+1}{2}}{1+be^{-k\cdot2}} \Leftrightarrow 1 = \frac{b+1}{2(1+be^{-k2})} \Leftrightarrow 1 = \frac{b+1}{2+2be^{-k2}} \Leftrightarrow b+1 = 2+2be^{-2k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{b-1}{2} = be^{2k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\frac{b-1}{2}}{b} = e^{-2k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{b-1}{2b} = e^{-2k} \Leftrightarrow \frac{b-1}{2b} = (\frac{1}{e^2})^k \Leftrightarrow k = \log_{\frac{1}{e^2}}{\frac{b-1}{2b}} \Leftrightarrow k = -\frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{b-1}{2b}) \Leftrightarrow k = \ln(\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b-1}})$$

Then I tried the third sentence with $k = \ln(\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b-1}})$

$$1 = \frac{\frac{b+1}{2}}{1+be^{-2\ln(\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b-1}})}}$$

This took me an $\infty$ of time to solve only to find out it was wrong, so I will skip the steps and tell you that both sides are always equal to 1 except for $x \in [-1;1]$ which show "ERROR"

How do I solve this?

Comment: The last part you discuss is unsurprising since it should boil to 1=1.

Could you talk about how you solved for the max? My understanding is that in the limit as time approaches infinite the expression should approach just $a$. You could solve for $a$ that way

Comment: @KitterCatter The max? You mean the 5 metres? I didn't, that value was given by the problem

Comment: I mean how did you use that information?

Comment: 1). You are missing a minus sign in the exponent, first equation in the statement. 2). I suppose we are given that $a,b,c>0$? 3). In that case, the function is increasing, and the supremum is never attained (hence the "approximate value.") You will find $a$ by solving $5 = \lim_{t\to\infty} h(t)$. From there, you get $b$ using the first sentence, and once you have all that the last sentence allows you to solve for $k$.

Comment: "I suppose we are given that $a,b,c>0a,b,c>0?$" It doesn't mention that, but since the function is for the growth of a tree I think it can be assumed that it is increasing. And ok, I'll try that

Comment: @KitterCatter I didn't.

Comment: @ClementC. Could you explain how to do that? i'm not very good with limits.

Comment: Assuming $k>0$, we have $ e^{-kt} \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} 0$, so $h(t) \xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} \frac{a}{1+b\cdot 0} = a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the function  $$h(t) = \frac{a}{1+be^{kt}}$$ and let us use the different given informations

> - the tree was 50 cm tall when it was planted
> - the maximum height the tree can have is 5 meters (approximate value)
> - after 2 years, the tree has twice the height it had when it was planted

As you wrote, the first one gives $$h(0)=\frac{a}{1+be^{k\times 0}}=\frac{a}{1+b}=\frac 12\tag 1$$ Assuming that $k$ is negative, the second one write $$h(\infty)=\frac{a}{1+be^{k\times \infty}}=\frac{a}{1}=5\tag 2$$ The third one gives $$h(2)=\frac{a}{1+be^{k\times 2}}=\frac{a}{1+b e^{2k}}=2h(0)=1.0\tag 3$$  So, from $(2)$ $a=5$; from $(1)$ $b=9$. Plugging these numbers in $(3)$ $$\frac 5 {1+9e^{2k}}=1\implies 4=9 e^{2k}\implies 2=3e^k\implies k=-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ All of that makes that we can rewrite the model as $$h(t)=\frac 5{1+9 e^{-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\,t}}$$

Using the formula, this would give the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 t & h(t) \\
 0 & 0.50 \\
 1 & 0.71 \\
 2 & 1.00 \\
 3 & 1.36 \\
 4 & 1.80 \\
 5 & 2.29 \\
 6 & 2.79 \\
 7 & 3.27 \\
 8 & 3.70 \\
 9 & 4.05 \\
 10 & 4.32 \\
 11 & 4.53 \\
 12 & 4.68 \\
 13 & 4.78 \\
 14 & 4.85 \\
 15 & 4.90 \\
 16 & 4.93 \\
 17 & 4.95 \\
 18 & 4.97 \\
 19 & 4.98 \\
 20 & 4.99 \\
\infty & 5.00
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$
h(t) = \frac{a}{1+be^{kt}}
$$
First information gives us.
$$
h(0) = \frac{a}{1+be^{k\cdot0}} = \frac{a}{1+b} = 0.5 \Leftrightarrow a = \frac{1+b}{2} 
$$
Second information gives us the height of the tree after long time.
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} h(t) \Rightarrow a = 5 \Rightarrow b = 9
$$
Third information gives $h(2) = 2h(0)$
$$
h(2) = 2h(0) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{5}{1+9e^{2k}} = 1 \Leftrightarrow 5 = 1 + 9e^{2k} \\
\Leftrightarrow\\
4 = 9e^{2k} \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
2k = \ln\left(\frac{4}{9}\right) \Leftrightarrow 
k = \ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)
$$

You wrote that $k = \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b-1}}\right)$, with $b=9$ you get the same $k$ as me.